# Decide convergence of this series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to prove the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {e^n\cdot n!}{n^n}$$ diverges?
I tried D'Alambert and result is 1 and I'm stuck with Raabe.

Comment: Use Stirling's approximation

Comment: The second answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683769/analysing-whether-a-series-is-convergent) may help.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: use
$$
n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n} \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n
$$
and deduce that the $n$-th term...

Comment: I can't use approximations, just standard tests like here:http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ralph/Classes/242/SeriesConvTests.pdf

Comment: I'm too old to pretend that Stirling's formula does not exist :-(

Comment: I understand =D thank you anyway

Comment: This looks like an overkill for such a simple problem...

Comment: I don't always like "elementary" approaches.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use this little trick?
$ \exp(n) = 1 + n +  n^2/2 +\cdots + n^n/n! + \cdots $. We then obtain that 
$\exp(n) n! = n! + n n! \cdots +  n^n + \cdots > n^n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let us define $$a_n=\frac {e^n\cdot n!}{n^n}$$ So, $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=e \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n$$ which is number greater than $1$.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: @DavidMitra. I know (I hope) but I did not want to go to the limits in order the OP continues from this. Cheers :)

Comment: but this equals 1, not greater :P

Comment: @DavidMitra. I always forget to tell you that the quotation from Leibnitz in your profile is one of my very favored. When much much younger, I used to say that I share something with Leibnitz (the naswer is $Leib$); unfortunately, that's all. Cheers :)

Comment: @Mare. The ratio I gave you is strictly larger than $1$ which is its limit for an infinite value of $n$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I'm not sure how to use it since limit is 1 so it's inconclusive

Comment: Sorry for being dense before... @Mare, this shows the sequence $(a_n)$ is increasing; since $a_1>0$, the sum can't converge. See the answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554070/how-is-displaystyle-lim-n-to-infty11-nn-e) to see why $b_n=\Bigl({n\over n+1}\Bigr)^n ={1\over \bigl(1+1/n\bigr)^n }> 1/e$; and hence why $a_{n+1}/a_n >1$. Very nice Claude!

Answer (score 1):

One more way: log the summand to get 
$$
\log e^n n! - n \log n  = n + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \log k - n \log n  \geq 1
$$
Hence the original function is greater than $e^1>0$, hence it diverges. This is because $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log k >\int_{1}^{n} \log x  = n \log n -n +1$

Comment: please see the edit

Comment: Great! thank you. This is acctualy a proof limit is infinity, which is even better! =)

Comment: please see the edit - the limit of the sequence itself is not infinity, it is $e$, but it means that the sum dies diverge. My mistake was not to consider the second term, which is also important. Sorry!

Comment: You can also check it by using Euler-Maclaurin approximation of sum with integrals up to the second term